# Select all text without ActiveX buttons

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to build a template that has ActiveX buttons for calling Sub procedures. At some point, I have to select the text and convert it to a table.

So, I have to find a way to select the text, without selecting the ActiveX controls.
I've figured there would be two approaches:

1. write a code that selects the text without objects (I only have
   ActiveX objects);
2. change the objects property in a way that they don't get
   selected using `Selection.WholeStory` or similar code.

I've tried the following methods, without success:

- using `Selection.WholeStory` -  it selects all text, including the ActiveX controls
- wraping the objects `Square`, not in line with the text, and positioning them outside the printing area - the objects still get selected
- putting the objects in the header - in this way, the buttons cannot be used/clicked
- putting the controls in a textbox - they still get selected

Do you know a way of achieving my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way was to put a section marker after the buttons (that are configured as "*in line*") and protect first section from editing.

Click on `Developer` -> `Restrict Editing` -> Check `Allow only this type of editing in the document` and Select `Filling in forms`. Then, click on `Select Sections` and Select the first section.

Next, in the VBA code, to select all the text, I use this code:

```
Dim rngText As Range
Set rngText = ActiveDocument.Sections(2).Range
rngText.Select
```